# Postgres pass more than 100 arguments to CONCAT function

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
"external_id" AS EVENT_ID,
"uuid"        AS EVENT_VERSION_ID,
"timestamp"   AS EVENT_VERSION_TIMESTAMP,
CONCAT('{',
'"timestamp": ', COALESCE(timestamp, NULL), ',',
'"uuid": ',   COALESCE("uuid", '"' || "uuid" || '"', 'null'), ',',
'"fraud": ',   COALESCE("fraud",'true','false', NULL), ',',
'"score": ', COALESCE("score", NULL), ',',
'"scoreTracking": ', COALESCE("scoreTracking", NULL), ',',
'"domain": ',   COALESCE("domain", '"' || "domain" || '"', NULL), ',',
'"event_occurred_at": ', COALESCE("event_occurred_at", NULL), ',',
'"event_received_at": ', COALESCE("event_received_at", NULL), ',',
'"event_type": ',   COALESCE("event_type", '"' || "event_type" || '"',     NULL), ',',
'"event_is_update": ',   COALESCE("event_is_update",'true', 'false', NULL), ',',
'"transaction_id": ',   COALESCE("transaction_id", '"' || "transaction_id" || '"', NULL), ',',
'"transaction_created_at": ', COALESCE("transaction_created_at", NULL), ',',
'"transaction_updated_at": ', COALESCE("transaction_updated_at", NULL), ',',
'"transaction_type": ',   COALESCE("transaction_type", '"' || "transaction_type" || '"', NULL), ',',
.
.
.
.
.
186 fields to concat......) AS EVENT_FIELDS;
```

However, postgres does not allow me to pass more than 100 arguments. I checked online and found read about **"variadic"** parameter. However, I'm not sure how to use it in this context.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you `CONCAT` 100 and `CONCAT` 86 then concat the two results?

Comment: By the way. Why is `NULL` one of your arguments to `coalesce`?

Comment: @Martin I don't think so, because I have to concat all the fields into the same fields say EVENT_FIELDS.

Comment: @MartinSmith Hmm so when the first parameter is null I want it to insert NULL instead of an empty value. Or so I understand. Did I misunderstand anything here ?

Comment: Did you try manual concatenation(using `||`) Instead of `concat()` function, ex .`select '"timestamp": '|| COALESCE(vrid, NULL)|| ','`  ?

Comment: @wingedpanther (notsureif) i'm sorry but i did not understand your example. All the fields inside concat function are selected as EVENT_FIELDS. Updated the question. Can you write explain how you want me to try again.

Comment: instead of using `concat()` fucntion you can use `|` symbols to concatenate text values, that is `select concat('A',', ','B')` is same as `select 'A'||','||'B'`(_using this method you could append more than 100 items_)

Comment: @wingedpanther tried that and it says ** ERROR: operator does not exist: || unknown
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 231 **

Comment: cast non string fields to text ie. if you've an integer field called `tran_id` make it `tran_id::text`

Comment: Are you looking for a result that looks like this - `{"timestamp:2017-01-01","uuid: 1255784",...}`?

Comment: all the fields I have are of type string

Comment: yes {"timestamp:2017-01-01","uuid: 1255784",...}

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create a JSON document. Why don't you use `row_to_json()` or `json_build_object()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - For some reason you reminded me of clippy there.

Comment: @Anusha `COALESCE(value, NULL)` does nothing: if `value` is `NULL`, then `COALESCE(value, NULL)` will still be `NULL`; if `value` is anything other than `NULL`, it will still be `value`. I think what you wanted was to subsitute the string `'NULL'` into your result, which would be `COALESCE(value, 'NULL')` - note the `'` marks.

Comment: In fact, this use of `COALESCE` doesn't make sense either: `COALESCE("transaction_type", '"' || "transaction_type" || '"', NULL)`. if `"transaction_type"` is `NULL`, it will attempt to calculate `'"' || "transaction_type" || '"'`; if `||` treated `NULL` like an empty string, you'd get the string `'""'`, which is probably not what you want; as it happens, it will just return `NULL`. So basically if `"transaction_type"` is `NULL`, the expression becomes `COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`row_to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) is the best way to get output like `{"timestamp:2017-01-01","uuid: 1255784",...}`

```
SELECT "external_id" AS EVENT_ID
      ,"uuid" AS EVENT_VERSION_ID
      ,"timestamp" AS EVENT_VERSION_TIMESTAMP
      ,row_to_json(( --{"timestamp:2017-01-01","uuid: 1255784",...}
            SELECT t
            FROM (
                SELECT timestamp
                      ,uuid
                      ,fraud
                      ,score
                      ,event_occurred_at
                ) t
            )) AS EVENT_DATA
FROM your_table
```